# sobrescrever determinada linha do arquivo txt

Tags: c#, txt

Estou fazendo um código onde preciso apagar uma determinada linha em um arquivo de texto (`.txt`) e colocar outra coisa nessa linha, gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso.

Exemplo: apagar a 2 linha **admin** e escrever **usuarioNovo**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar algo como:

```
private void ChangeUser(string currentUser, string newUser, int position)
{
    string sourceFile = @"C:\Test\root.txt";

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile);

    if(lines.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Seu arquivo está vazio!");
        return;
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sourceFile))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            // Verifica se é a segunda linha e se o conteúdo da mesma é igual ao usuário atual
            if(i == position && lines[i] == currentUser)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(newUser);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Onde `currentUser` é o usuário que você quer substituir, `newUser` é o novo usuário e `position` é qual a linha em que deve-se procurar os dados anteriores.

No seu caso, `currentUser` é "admin", `newUser` é "usuarioNovo" e `position` é 1, devido ao fato que um `array` começa na posição 0, logo a segunda posição é 1.

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado pela ajuda :D